# Is there any built in support for Ansible to set an expired sudoers password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, sudo

Currently i have a bash script that uses expect to mass reset my sudoers password on machines upon expiration, is there anything built into ansible that would support something similiar? It would be more convenient if ansible did it since it can group aws hosts by tag so i can reset passwords on specific ec2 instances identified by tag rather than a identifying by IP address, the alternate is to write this functionality into the bash script(s) but it seems like a bad idea if ansible has 80% of the functionality already there.

Comment: You can execute custom shell script on the remote machine using [`script`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'no'.  Ansible does not currently include any modules (in either [ansible-modules-core](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core) or [ansible-modules-extras](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras)) that specifically deal with sudoers.

Most people who need to manage sudoers files via ansible do so with [templates](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) to manage the `/etc/sudoers` file and/or files under `/etc/sudoers.d`.

You might be able to find some roles related to managing sudoers in [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/), but those would be third-party offerings, which you may or may not be interested in.